# Blazor File Security

Tags: file, security, blazor

I have implemented Blazor client side token security example as per example provided from Chris Sainty. And it worked very well. However I do have one Problem. I do plan to upload some documents on the server pdf, excel and etc. And because all security check is executed from the Blazor framework, which works fine when I have to restrict database access, I couldn’t figure out how to use the same token based security in order to restrict a file access as well. In other words when someone scan the site and type the link to the file direct - the file is available without restrictions. I am using Blazor Hosted solution which is hosted on IIS Server.

Answer (score 2):

[This is how Static files in ASP.NET Core are handled when you want to control access to resources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-3.1#static-file-authorization)

Just provide secured Web Api end points (decorated with the Authorize attribute).

You also need to pass the Jwt token with your HTTP requests, when you want to access those resources. If it isn't clear, please ask questions, and I'll tell you what to do...